# Mongodb Debian 6.0 failed to init

Tags: mongodb, debian, init.d

I really need some help...I have been trying to install Mongodb on Debian 6 following the instructions in mongodb´s site ([link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)). I keep gettig a weird error when trying to start using the init.d script. Searching for hour in Google I have found that there seems to be a problem with mongodb´s init script for Debian, however I have not found a fix.

Thanks so much!!

This the error I get on install:

*invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely hitting the issue described in [SERVER-6008](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6008) - there is a fix coming in the next release (2.4.7) but that has not been released at the time of writing this answer.

The workaround is to manually get, and use, the patched init script in the meantime.  You can see that init script here (change is checked into 2.5.2):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r2.5.2/debian/init.d